# Pass props to {children()} for use in component of child page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

How can I pass props to a component of a child page?

The prop that I am trying to pass is `onToggleBooking: PropTypes.func` which is defined in my `layout.js` (root file) as

```
lass Template extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        isBookingVisible: false,
    }
    this.handleToggleBooking = this.handleToggleBooking.bind(this)
}

handleToggleBooking() {
    this.setState({
        isBookingVisible: !this.state.isBookingVisible
    })
}

render() {
    const { children } = this.props
    return (
        <main className={`${this.state.isBookingVisible ? 'is-booking-visible' : ''}`}>
            {children()}
        </main>
        )
    }
}

Template.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.func
}
export default Template
```

I want to pass `onToggleBooking={this.handleToggleBooking}` prop to `{children()}` so I am able to pass and use in a component of one of the child pages.

To do this I tried

```
{
  children.map(child => React.cloneElement(child, {
    onToggleBooking
  }))
}
```

But I receive an error of `children.map` is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's ideal to render children via props like:

```
  render() {
    return <div>{ this.props.children }</div>
  }
```

Rendering children as prop functions is doable but you hould take a look to ensure your class the children are extended from is configured correctly, and the resulting render template is valid:

```
class CoolClass extends Component {
  render() {                  
      return this.props.children()
  }
}
```

And then the template you call when rendering should look like:

```
<CoolClass>
  {() => <h1>Hello World!</h1>}
</CoolClass>
```

You are close with passing sown the toggle handler using `onToggleBooking={this.handleToggleBooking}`, but it needs to be provided as a prop itself on a component or child your passing down. You can either edit the constructor to include it with your `props.children`, but that may be a pain to debug correctly calling `children()` `prop` as a fucntion.